# listbox to text document no overwriting

Tags: vb.net, listbox, documents, overwrite

hello i am using this code to save listbox1 contents to .txt document it works. but as soon i reopen the program and save new text it overwriting original text how can i make it add as an additional text rather then overwriting. thank you so much every 1.

```
Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
Dim i As Integer
W = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\test\test.txt")

For i = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
    W.WriteLine(ListBox2.Items.Item(i))
Next
W.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
W = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\test\test.txt", True)
```

The true statement indicates that you want to append text to an existing file.

Comment: thank you so much you are he best it works perefeklty i left u 1 positive feed back cheers

Answer (score -1):

This is great!

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

Dim count As Integer = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("location").Length
    If count <= 9 Then
        MsgBox("less then 10")
    Else
        MsgBox("more then 10")
    End If
End Sub
```